# How to list all containers in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

How do i list all containers in Kubernetes cluster using `kubectl`?

Current [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-overview/#resource-types) doesn't mention anything like 'container' resource.

```
kubectl get pod -o json
```

lists all pods which contains container descriptions. But is it possible to list containers as first class citizens?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will get all container with the namespace in a pretty format:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=custom-columns=NameSpace:.metadata.namespace,NAME:.metadata.name,CONTAINERS:.spec.containers[*].name
```

Comment: To prevent expansion of wildcards by my shell, I had to put a single quote around the `-o=` value, like `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o='custom-columns=NameSpace:.metadata.namespace,NAME:.metadata.name,CONTAINERS:.spec.containers[*].name'`

Answer (score 5):

When you don't use the namespace flag you are only looking in the default namespace. Try

```
kubectl get pod --all-namespaces
```

That will list all the pods in your cluster

You can filter via namespace like

```
kubectl get pod -n kube-system
```

To show all containers

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath={.items[*].spec.containers[*].name}
```

Comment: Commands in the answer list pods. Is there any way how to list containers in a similar way?

Comment: you can do this `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath={.items[*].spec.containers[*].name}` its not as nicely printed out

Comment: Thanks. Could you please copy it to the main answer since the question is really about containers, not pods?

Comment: done.. I made an edit

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

EDIT : damn, burned ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can list all containers in default namespace

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].name}"
```

Also you can user --namespace and --selector.

```
kubectl get pods --namespace default --selector app=nginx -o=jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].name}"
```

Reference

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl describe pods <pod name>
```

This will list containers in pods of given name.

Answer (score -1):

you can use -A shortcut instead of --all-namespaces

```
kubectl get pods -A
```